# UPS for 750W to be up 6 hours

Tags: server

I have a Dell PowerEdge t630 server 750W power with PF 94%, I need a UPS that make my server Up for 6 hours at least

please advice the UPS capacity in KVA

thanks

Comment: 750W is probably the peak power, not the average. Keep in mind that switches, routers, etc. also need power too, or your server being up is rather useless. Air conditioning needs power too. Also, for such a long time, maybe a generator is more appropriate (but can be a fire hazard).

Comment: We have a separated UPS for router and switch , I need this UPS for Server only as this will be a local server for developers

Answer (score 0):

The UPS power capacity will need to be at least 750VA. With a power factor that high, watts and VA are effectively the same. To supply 750W, you need a 750VA UPS.

Make sure the UPS can also supply 750 watts. Not every 750 VA UPS can supply 750 watts. Many UPSes can supply more reactive power than they can real power. You may wind up needing a UPS rated for 1,000 VA to get one that can supply 50 watts.

The amount of time the UPS needs to last has no effect on how much power it needs to be able to supply. A 100 watt light bulb needs 100 watts, whether it's on for a minute or a year.

I would caution you that there is no reliable way to compute a UPS's run time at a given load based on its stated efficiency or reserve time at other load values. [Battery efficiency changes drastically with load.](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Peukert's_law) For example, halving the battery size will often cut the run time by much more than half. The only reliable way to predict UPS run time is to ask the manufacturer or look at at the manufacturer's graph of run time versus load.

Note that doubling the battery size will typically *more* than double the run time. This means that, for example, a UPS that claims to run for one hour at half load will almost certainly *not* run for half an hour at full load, it will usually run for much less time than that.

For such a long run time, look for a UPS that can be expanded with additional battery modules. The manufacturer should provide a chart that will tell you how long each module will last, and that will let you figure out how many modules you will need. Be aware that adding more battery modules often increases the charge time.

Comment: do you mean 750VA or 750KVA cause there's no such capacity available and you don't mentioned if this per hour or how log will it lease

Comment: @Linux1Man Sorry, it should be 750VA (corrected). But really, the VA rating is irrelevant in your case. Your power factor is so close to 1 that what really matters is that the UPS can supply 750W. A 750W UPS should be able to run your load. If you read my answer carefully, it explains why there's no special answer to how long it will last -- you have to look at the manufacturer's run time charts to tell that.

Comment: @Linux1Man You're asking the wrong question. Your question is like: "I need a car that can go 400 miles on a tank of gas. How many horsepower should the engine be?"